# Ubuntu filesystem not writable

Tags: partitioning, permissions, filesystem, ssd

We have a strange problem with Ubuntu filesystem. The problem is, I cant completely reconstruct what happend. The user said, he wanted to format a usb disk. From the bash history I could see, that he installed gnome-disk-utility. He said, that he might have accidently formatted not the usb disk but the system disk or anything else.

However, the system disk is still there, we can log in but only to the shell because X wont start (but the luks GUI screen does, is it independent from X?). When we try `startx` we get error message, that X cant write a lock file.

However, I tried to write any file with `touch` in the home folder, but that does not work, even not with `sudo` because the system is not writable. So because its a (relatively new) SSD I assumed, that there happened a lot write commands and therefore the disk died in a way and is only readable on a hardware basis. But when I connect the disk as an external to another computer, I can write to it.

So, what might have happened, that the filesystem is not writable, even for sudo?

thats all I can find in fstab that is not comments:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=XXX /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/it--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
```

***edit:*** Ok it really looks like it is a mount problem, I did `mount -o remount,rw /` and suddenly the system started. Cool. But how can I make this solid for the booting?

Comment: Might be mounted read only? Check the `/etc/fstab` for any `ro` options on the root drive.

Comment: @nixpower I updated the post with fstab output

Comment: Do you happen to know the brand of the SSD? Some suggest firmware updates have fixed such problems.

Comment: ok it was actually a mount problem, I updated the question

Comment: Are you *certain* those are the only two lines in the `/etc/fstab` that aren't comments? Nothing is being mounted to `/`. On my Ubuntu Server, I have a line like `/dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root /  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1`.

Comment: yes iam sure, it also surprises me, but maybe there is another default file that is only overwritten by /etc/fstab and there is a mount type set for /?! So, what should I put in fstab to mount it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was, that the `/` was mounted readonly when booting. Therefore I set the line:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 defaults
```

in `/etc/fstab`. But I still don't understand why that happened, because there is no other line in `fstab` that would mount root as readonly.